# MapMarker does not update description onPress immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to learn how to use React Native maps and I am trying to add in custom Map Markers. For some reason, when I try to use the following code, the image updates properly but the description does not update properly until the second click. The first click will show "not selected" but clicking on the same marker will show the actual text I want. How can I fix this?

Since the image is updating to the newImage, I know 
this.state.selectedMarkerIndex === i
but the same equality does not apply to description for some reason?

```
    state = {busText:[]}
    fetchData=(i, index)=>{    
    fetch('LINK TO GET BUSES'+ i.toString() + '/buses', {method:'GET'})
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
            selectedMarkerIndex: index,
            busText: responseJson
        },
        ()=>{
          console.log("selected index: " + this.state.selectedMarkerIndex)
        }
    )

    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.busText));
    console.log("_______________________________________________________");
})
}


  renderMarkers = ()=>{
  return busStops.stops.map((stop, i) => {
  return <Marker marker
    key={ `${i}` }

    coordinate={{latitude: stop.location.latitude, longitude: stop.location.longitude}}

    title = {stop.stopName}
    image = {this.state.selectedMarkerIndex === i ? newImage : busStopImage} 
    description={this.state.selectedMarkerIndex === i ? JSON.stringify(this.state.busText) : "not selected"}

    onPress={() => {
        this.fetchData(stop.stopID, i)
        console.log(this.state.selectedMarkerIndex + "i :" + i)
      }

    }

    />
})

}
```

I expect the description of the MapMarker to be updated when I click on it with what is fetched but that is not occurring.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things: To guarantee execution after setState you'll need to put your

```
this.setState({busText: responseJson})
```

in the `fetchData()` callback.  Even better, set busText state earlier, where you're setting selectedMarkerIndex state.

Also for what it's worth, if you're having response time issues, try dropping some of your console.log() calls.  Native (especially iOS) gets bogged down by them.

Comment: I have changed it to where you suggested but the issue still persists. When I click on a marker, it still shows as "not selected" when it is selected. 

`image = {this.state.selectedMarkerIndex === i ? newImage : busStopImage} 
        description={this.state.selectedMarkerIndex === i ? JSON.stringify(this.state.busText) : "not selected"}`

They should both evaluatae to true but the second line (description) does not while image does evaluate to true for some reason.

Comment: You've changed nothing.  The code above is exactly the same.

I thought your question was `The first click will show "not selected" but clicking on the same marker will show the actual text I want. How can I fix this?`

Comment: I am sorry. I made the changes on my editor and not here(changed it now). What you stated is my question. For some reason, The first click still shows "not selected" after trying what you initially suggested.

Comment: It looks right to me.  Is the behavior the same in both simulator and the device?

Comment: It is same in both.

Comment: Try getting rid of your console messages.  Do you use react-devtools (With React Native it opens in an Electron window)?  You can check your state & props there as well as the console. Your console.log onPress might be blocking a state change.